# How to loop function using a list of variables?

Tags: python

I have a function that prints OHLCV data for stock prices from a websocket. It works but I have to copy it for each variable (Var1 to Var14) to get each individual stock data. How would I automate this process given that I have list:

```
varlist = [var1, var2, var3...var14]
```

and my code is:

```
def process_messages_for_var1(msg):
    if msg['e'] == 'error':
        print(msg['m'])
   # If message is a trade, print the OHLC data
    else:
    # Convert time into understandable structure
    transactiontime = msg['k']['T'] / 1000
    transactiontime = datetime.fromtimestamp(transactiontime).strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
    # Process this message once websocket starts
    print("{} - {} - Interval {} - Open: {} - Close: {} - High: {} - Low: {} - Volume: {}".
          format(transactiontime,msg['s'],msg['k']['i'],msg['k']['o'],msg['k']['c'],msg['k']['h'],msg['k']['l'],msg['k']['v']))
    # Also, put information into an array
    kline_array_msg = "{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(
        msg['k']['T'],msg['k']['o'],msg['k']['c'],msg['k']['h'],msg['k']['l'],msg['k']['v'])         
# Insert at first position
    kline_array_dct[var1].insert(0, kline_array_msg)
    if (len(kline_array_dct[var1]) > window): 
        # Remove last message when res_array size is > of FIXED_SIZE
        del kline_array_dct[var1][-1]
```

I'm hoping to get the following result (notice how function name also changes):

```
def process_messages_for_var2(msg):
   if msg['e'] == 'error':
       print(msg['m'])
   # If message is a trade, print the OHLC data
   else:
   # Convert time into understandable structure
   transactiontime = msg['k']['T'] / 1000
   transactiontime = datetime.fromtimestamp(transactiontime).strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
   # Process this message once websocket starts
   print("{} - {} - Interval {} - Open: {} - Close: {} - High: {} - Low: {} - Volume: {}".
          format(transactiontime,msg['s'],msg['k']['i'],msg['k']['o'],msg['k']['c'],msg['k']['h'],msg['k']['l'],msg['k']['v']))
    # Also, put information into an array
    kline_array_msg = "{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(
        msg['k']['T'],msg['k']['o'],msg['k']['c'],msg['k']['h'],msg['k']['l'],msg['k']['v'])         
# Insert at first position
    kline_array_dct[var2].insert(0, kline_array_msg)
    if (len(kline_array_dct[var2]) > window): 
        # Remove last message when res_array size is > of FIXED_SIZE
        del kline_array_dct[var2][-1]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind fixing your indentation (for example, for `if`/`else`)?  That'll make your code easier to read.

Comment: It seems that the only difference between the two functions is one references `var1` and the other references `var2`.  If I'm reading that correctly, couldn't you simply pass the variable in as a function argument?

Comment: Hi, thanks the reply. How do you indent? I wasn't able to tab.

Comment: That's correct, the only differences are var1 and var2. I'm still new to coding so not sure how to do so.

Comment: To indent, just use four spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the function so that it takes one of the `var`s as an argument.  I.e.,

```
def process_messages(msg, var):
    ...

    kline_array_dct[var].insert(0, kline_array_msg)
    if (len(kline_array_dct[var]) > window): 
        # Remove last message when res_array size is > of FIXED_SIZE
        del kline_array_dct[var][-1]
```

Comment: I would also include a `for` loop to call the process for every var in the list instead of calling it 14 separate times

Comment: Hmm the problem is later on I need to start the websocket this way:    (1) varlist =  [var1, var2, var3...var14]  and (2) messages = [process_messages_for_var1, process_messages_for_var2...process_messages_for_var14] and pass it through (3) run_klines = list(map(lambda args: bm_kline.start_kline_socket(*args), zip(varlist, messages))). How would I go about to replace function (2)?

Comment: Is `messages` supposed to be a list of functions?

Comment: Yes. Its a list of functions that stores process_messages

Comment: Since I don't know how `bm_kline.start_kline_socket` uses its arguments, it's hard for me to know how things should be arranged.  Perhaps you could look at the `partial` function from the `functools` module.

Comment: For example, if you altered `process_messages` so that `var` was the first argument, you could do `messages = [functools.partial(process_messages,var) for var in varlist]`.

Comment: How it operates is bm_kline.start_kline_socket(symbol, message) where symbol is the stock ticker and message is how the OHLCV data is outputted. Just tried your functools method but wasn't able to do it successfully. I might honestly just put this question aside for now.

Comment: That’s what I’m doing. I answered your question while waiting for a response to my question. But I wasn’t getting responses so I just went to bed to check on it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

If the processes are generally the same, just define one of them, and give it more arguments:

```
def process_messages(msg, var)
```

Then, you can adjust your process code to run through each var when you call it. You can do this by removing the numbered vars in the process code:

```
if msg['e'] == 'error':
   print(msg['m'])
   # If message is a trade, print the OHLC data
   else:
   # Convert time into understandable structure
   transactiontime = msg['k']['T'] / 1000
   transactiontime = datetime.fromtimestamp(transactiontime).strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
   # Process this message once websocket starts
   print("{} - {} - Interval {} - Open: {} - Close: {} - High: {} - Low: {} - Volume: {}".
          format(transactiontime,msg['s'],msg['k']['i'],msg['k']['o'],msg['k']['c'],msg['k']['h'],msg['k']['l'],msg['k']['v']))
    # Also, put information into an array
    kline_array_msg = "{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(
        msg['k']['T'],msg['k']['o'],msg['k']['c'],msg['k']['h'],msg['k']['l'],msg['k']['v'])         
# Insert at first position
    kline_array_dct[var].insert(0, kline_array_msg)
    if (len(kline_array_dct[var]) > window): 
        # Remove last message when res_array size is > of FIXED_SIZE
        del kline_array_dct[var][-1]
```

Then, create a simple `for` loop to call the process for each var in the list:

```
for var in varList:
    process_messages("msg", var)
```

The for loop will call the process for each var in the list.

Comment: The problem is later on I need to start the websocket this way: (1) varlist = [var1, var2, var3...var14] and (2) messages = [process_messages_for_var1, process_messages_for_var2...process_messages_for_var14] and pass and start the websocket via (3) run_klines = list(map(lambda args: bm_kline.start_kline_socket(*args), zip(varlist, messages))). How would I go about to replace function (2)?

Comment: also I get TypeError: string indices must be integers. "msg" is not a string but its to refer to the dictionary of OHLCV data